# Spyder cannot be launched under Anaconda

Tags: anaconda

I installed Anaconda3 and created a TensorFlow environment. In this environment, I installed TensorFlow 1.12.0 and Tensorflow-probability 0.5.0. Then I installed Spyder, but neither of the two Spyder instances in the base and in this tf environment can be launched, whether I run spyder from the Ananconda prompt or from the Start menu. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. In the prompt, run `spyder --reset` and the following information will be displayed:

```
Reset Spyder settings to defaults 
removing: C:\Users\yshen\.spyder-py3\onlinehelp   
removing: C:\Users\yshen\.spyder-py3\spyder.ini 
removing: C:\Users\yshen\.spyder-py3\temp.py 
removing: C:\Users\yshen\.spyder-py3\template.py 
removing: C:\Users\yshen\.spyder-py3\history.py 
removing: C:\Users\yshen\.spyder-py3\history_internal.py 
removing: C:\Users\yshen\.spyder-py3\workingdir 
removing: C:\Users\yshen\.spyder-py3\.ropeproject 
removing: C:\Users\yshen\.spyder-py3\langconfig 
removing: C:\Users\yshen\.spyder-py3\spyder.lock
```

Run `spyder` again and it will launch successfully.